# how to create amp pages in nuxtJS with external css

Tags: nuxt.js, amp-html

tried **@nuxtjs/amp** on my project, the main problem is :

in "nuxt.config.js" File 'extractCss' is true and it works for all layouts & i can't make any exception for my ampLayout

in order to make a valid amp page i need to put all css codes internal

is there anyway to keep {"extractCss": true} & make exception for amp pages?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Try:

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
{
  hooks: {
    // This hook is called before generatic static html files for SPA mode
    'generate:page': ({ page }) => {
      if (/^\/amp\//gi.test(page.path)) {
        page.html = modifyHtml(page.html)
      }
    },
    // This hook is called before rendering the html to the browser
    'render:route': (url, page) => {
      if (/^\/amp\//gi.test(url)) {
        page.html = modifyHtml(page.html)
      }
    }
  }
  
}
```

**modifyHtml**

```js
const modifyHtml = (html) => {
  const styleConcat = renderSync({ file: 'assets/css/amp.scss', outputStyle: 'compressed' }).css.toString()
  html = html.replace('</head>', `<style amp-custom>${styleConcat}</style></head>`)
  html = html.replace(/<link[^>]*rel="stylesheet" href=".*\.css[^>]*>/gi, '')
  html = html.replace(/<link[^>]*rel="preload" href=".*\.js[^>]*>/gi, '')
  return html
}
```